# Better Way For Nested For Loops

Tags: java

I was just wanting to check and see if there is a better way to do this nested for loop. Below is the code:

```
   if(order){
        outer: for (Object item : list) {
            if (item.detail() == 1) {
                for (Object2 item2 : list2) {
                    if(item2.getOrderNbr() == item.getOrderNbr()) {
                        //non-related
                        break outer;
                    }
            }
        }
    }
```

For a summary of what I am trying to do. I have two lists, the first list has a list of similar objects but has an extra field that tells me if an order is on a certain spot. If it is, it then goes to the second list and tries to find the corresponding object in that list based on the order numbers since the order numbers will match. The second list does not have the property to tell me if it is on a certain spot so I have to use both lists.

Comment: Java 8 Streams might help you...

Comment: You might just store the second list as part of (a reference) the first.  That way the list of orders is always directly attached to the first object.  I'm a little unsure what this actually represents though or what you're trying to do, so it's hard to give examples or definitive answers.

Answer (score 0):

This Stream might help you:

```
list.stream()
    .filter(item -> item.detail() == 1)
    .anyMatch(item1 -> list2.stream()
                            .anyMatch(item2 -> item1.getOrderNbr() == item2.getOrderNbr()));
```

Using [`Stream::anyMatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-) twice assures there is the condition you have raised met. You can perform an action based on the returned `boolean`.

If you want to return that item, use a different approach using [`Stream::filter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-) which is not a terminal operation like the operation above and allows the Stream to continue. [`Stream::findAny`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findFirst--) retruns an `Optional` of the qualifed instance. Remember that filtering might return multiple instances in case `getOrderNbr` is equal for more items:

```
list.stream()
    .filter(item -> item.detail() == 1)
    .filter(item1 -> list2.stream.anyMatch(item2 -> item1.getOrderNbr() == item2.getOrderNbr()))
    .findFirst();
```

Comment: @facepalm42: Yeah, but Stream API is based on fluent interface (kind of builder) and used as is with no syntactic sugar (except lambdas though). I'll take a look on how is LINQ implemented, out of curiosity :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are checking `secondList` all the time based on `orderNbr`, it is good to create a `Map` and use it for faster retrieval.

I am assuming your second list contains class named `Order` for simplicity of understanding

You can try this:

```
Map<Integer, Order> orderMap = new HashMap<>();
list2.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Order::getOrderNbr));

list1
    .stream()
    .filter(f -> f.getDetail() == 1)
    .map(First::getOrderNbr)
    .forEach(orderNo -> {
        Order order = orderMap.get(orderNo);
        // your-code
    });
```

**Note:** This code also supports multiple orders in `list1` that are at same spot.